# Why can't I see a text input when I have a canvas next to it?

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="kartina" width="100" height="100">
<form>
<input type="text" id="xyz" value="abc">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The input box does not appear.  However, when I comment out the `canvas` like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<!--<canvas id="kartina" width="100" height="100">-->
<form>
<input type="text" id="xyz" value="abc">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

then the input box is visible.

Why is the canvas preventing the text box from showing up?  Is it covering it?  If so, how can I force them to be in separate parts of the page?

EDIT: I'm viewing in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I see, your canvas tag is not closed. Below is a modified version of your code with the tag closed, that displays both the canvas and the form.

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas  id="kartina" width="100" height="100">    **</canvas>**
<form>
 <input type="text" id="xyz" value="abc" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps :-).

Comment: Yes, that was it.  This hadn't been an issue previously when the canvas was the only element in the body.  I'll accept in a few minutes.